# _mm256_blend_pd : merge elements from two vector

Tags: intrinsics, avx

I have a function as below, and I'd like to leverage some avx intrinsics to speed it up.

```
 bool Box::intersect(Line & line)
 {
    double left_x = line.x0();
    double right_x = line.x1();
    double lower_y = line.y0();
    double upper_y = line.y1();
    
    if (left_x > right_x) { std::swap(left_x, right_x); }
    if (lower_y > upper_y) { std::swap(lower_y, upper_y); }

    double box[4] = {x0(), y0(), x1(), y1()};

    if (box[0] < left_x || box[2] > right_x || box[3] < lower_y || box[1] > upper_y)
    {
       return false;
    }

    if (box[0]  <= left_x && box[2]  >= right_x && box[1]  <= lower_y && box[3]  >= upper_y)
    {
       return true;
    }

    if (line.x0() == line.x1() || line.y0() == line.y1())
    {
       return true;
    }

     return false;
 }
```

For the first two if condition, I want to make two __mm256 vector and compare it

```
double line_arr[4] = {left_x, right_x, lower_y, upper_y};
__m256d vec_line = _mm256_loadu_pd(line_arr);
__m256d vec_box = _mm256_loadu_pd(box);

auto vec_left = _mm256_blend_pd( vec_box, vec_line, /*???*/);
auto vec_right = _mm256_blend_pd( vec_box, vec_line, /*???*/);
auto vec_res = _mm256_cmp_pd(vec_left, vec_right, _CMP_LT_OS);
if (vec_res[0] || vec_res[1] || vec_res[2] || vec_res[3])
{
   return false;
}
```

The problem is, how could I select elements from different vector and merge them into one __m256 vector by using _mm256_blend_pd?

Comment: `blendpd` takes an compile-time-constant blend control.  Maybe you're looking for `blendvpd`, `_mm256_blendv_pd`?  It does a variable blend, useful with `cmp` results.

Comment: Or actually you want `_mm256_min_pd` and `_mm256_max_pd` if I'm understanding your scalar code correctly; instead of conditional swap, just use a min/max comparator to sort pairs of numbers.  (Your question title would be more useful to future readers if it described what you actually want, instead of just what `_mm256_blend_pd` does.)

Comment: FYI, `vec_res[0] || vec_res[1] || vec_res[2] || vec_res[3]` is a horrible way to write that condition.  Probably some compilers won't compile it to `_mm256_movemask_pd(vec_res) != 0` because they don't realize that the elements are all-zero or all-one bits (-NaN), and just see the short-circuit logical OR.  (Is `NaN` even true in that context?  I guess `NaN != 0` is true.)

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes, yeah I realize I can replace std::swap with _mm256_min_pd  and max, but in the following section, I don't want to make 4 _mm256 and compare them, since the data is the same, but the order is different. what instruction can I use to reorder the __mm256 vector before I cmp them? thanks

Comment: If you want to combine and reorder elements from two vectors, [`_mm256_shuffle_pd`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=AVX&text=shufpd&ig_expand=6418) could work. It has some limitations (check the link). I don't really understand your function, it certainly does not determine if a line (segment) intersects a box ...

Comment: @chtz Do you have an example about how _mm256_shuffle_pd works?  I am confused about parameter imm8. 
Give 4 elements in each __m256,  auto r = _mm256_shuffle_pd(a, b, ?), how can I get first & third elements from a, and second & fourth elements from b?

Comment: Oh, I see, you have 4 coordinates for one line in one vector.  Don't do that if you can avoid it; check four lines in parallel against the same or different boxes (with separate vectors of four x0 components...) instead of sorting horizontally (within a single vector) or something.  If you can't make the rest of your program SIMD-friendly, you might still be able to gain something out of using two 128-bit vectors for the line, so you can do min/max between them for x's and y's in parallel?  I'm confused because your scalar code doesn't appear to be blending between box and line coordinates.

Comment: `_mm256_shuffle_pd(a, b, ?)` will actually get 0th and 2nd from `a` and 1st and 3rd from `b` (mostly because of an AVX-quirk that it mostly behaves like two SSE vectors independently). However, you can't get elements from the other half.

Comment: Thank you @PeterCordes, Can you provide more details about how can I check 4 lines in parallel through some code?  the first `if` condition is to check the line segment is outside the box, the second is to check the line is totally inside the box.  I am confused about how to check them in parallel.

Comment: See Slides + text: SIMD at Insomniac Games (GDC 2015) - https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015/ for a talk that introduces the idea of arranging your data as a struct-of-arrays (of x0 coords, of x1 coods, etc.) to allow vertical SIMD instead of messing around with horizontal stuff within one SIMD vector.  Also other links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info

Comment: Re: "the first `if` condition is to check the line segment is outside the box, [...]": No, it actually checks if at least one endpoint is outside the box (assuming `box[0] >= box[2] && box[1] <= box[3]`) -- that does not imply that the entire segment is outside the box.