# C++ Why is my scalar code as slow as SIMD (AVX intrinsics) version?

Tags: c++, intrinsics, avx, scalar

I'd like to speed up my function by using avx intrinsic.

however, my avx code is as slow as my scalar code. How should I adjust them?

Here is my scalar code: The length of a[] and b[] is both 4.

```
bool func(double[] a, double[] b)
{
   if (a[0] > a[2]) { std::swap(a[0], a[2]); }
   if (a[1] > a[3]) { std::swap(a[1], a[3]); }

   if (b[2] < a[0] || b[0] > a[2] || b[3] < a[2] || b[1] > a[3])
   {
      return false;
   }

   if (b[0] <= a[0] && b[2] >= a[2] && b[1] <= a[1] && b[3] >= a[3])
   {
      return true;
   }

   if (a[0] == a[2] || a[1] == a[3])
   {
      return true;
   }
    
   return false;
}
```

and here is my avx ver.
I prepare 2 vectors and compare them at once to replace the scalar if condition above.:

```
bool func(double[] a, double[] b)
{
   if (a[0] > a[2]) { std::swap(a[0], a[2]); }
   if (a[1] > a[3]) { std::swap(a[1], a[3]); }

   __m256d vec_1 = _mm256_set_pd(b[2], b[3], a[2], a[3]);
   __m256d vec_2 = _mm256_set_pd(a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1]);
   int mask = _mm256_movemask_pd(_mm256_cmp_pd(vec_1, vec_2, _CMP_LT_OQ));
   if (mask != 0) { return false; }

   vec_1 = _mm256_set_pd(b[0], b[1], a[2], a[3]);
   vec_2 = _mm256_set_pd(a[0], a[1], b[2], b[3]);
   mask = _mm256_movemask_pd(_mm256_cmp_pd(vec_1, vec_2, _CMP_GT_OQ));
   if (mask == 0) { return true; }

   if (a[0] == a[2] || a[1] == a[3])
   {
      return true;
   }
    
   return false;
}
```

Any examples will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: This code is memory bound, and the scalar version may benefit from shortcut evaluation. If you explain what the code is meant to do, maybe we can find better ways.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  the function is to check if a line (a[]) is overlapped with a rectangle (b[]), which a and b are represented by 4 coords ( x0, y0, x1, y1 ). assuming rectangle b is parallel to x and y axis.

Comment: Are you using compiler optimisations? If so then the compiler may well perform the same optimisation itself, if not then your benchmarks are meaningless

Comment: What do you call overlapped ? I don't see the case of the line crossing the rectangle even though its endpoints are outside.

Comment: You can test if two axis-aligned rectangles have an empty intersection in 4 comparisons.

Comment: @AlanBirtles , I've checked the assembly. the scalar one is already using xmm registers, while I can see some ymm introduced by my avx code.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  the first if condition is to check at least one endpoint is outside the box (assuming box[0] >= box[2] && box[1] <= box[3]), and the second one is to check the line is totally inside the box.

Comment: What do you know about the statistical distribution of the segments wrt the window ?

Comment: Here is an almost identical question which uses the same (dubious) logic to check for intersections: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70832597/mm256-blend-pd-merge-elements-from-two-vector

Comment: Ignoring the fact that the function likely does not what you want -- one reason the AVX function is not faster is likely that it spends a lot of time composing the vectors -- this can't be made up by the few comparisons which are saved. Maybe consider using just 128bit vectors (and use `_mm_setr_pd(a[0], a[1])` etc to use the natural ordering -- or directly a `_mm_loadu_pd(a)`). This would also allow to replace the first two branches by `_mm_max_pd`/`_mm_min_pd` calls, and the last branch can also be a vectorized comparison.

Comment: @chtz Thanks for your sharing, could you be more specific about how to replace the first two branches with `_mm_max_pd` or min of two `_m128d` ? forgive me that I am a rookie.

Comment: @HansStitcher: A debug build would still use XMM registers for scalar FP, and AVX intrinsics would still use YMM registers.  The way to tell if it's optimized is that it's not storing / reloading between every C++ statement.  But lack of optimization may not be the problem.  As chtz points out, `_mm256_set_pd(b[2], b[3], a[2], a[3]);` is probably more expensive than you think, especially since the compiler can't do contiguous loads of two halves since you have `b[2]` as the top element, then `b[3]` below that. So `b[2..3]` needs to be swapped.  And scalar branching is cheap if it predicts well